# Compile source for a project like checkstyle from SourceForge

Tags: java, ant, build, compilation, sourceforge

Hi I would like to compile the source of CheckStyle from SourceForge. Can anyone please provide directions as to how I can compile the project and get an executable Jar file.

Comment: its a maven based project, so install maven on the system and "mvn compile package"

Comment: Hi @MehulRathod thanks for the info. It actually compiled correctly for version 5.5 not 5.6. Now, when I try to run using `java -jar checkstyle-5.5.jar` it gives the following error
**Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
checkstyle-5.5.jar**